# scroll bar is too long

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

My scroll bar too long, I want it to be in the same size as the text:

[image]

my code:

```
self.title('Canvas')
self.geometry('400x600')
canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white',width=500,height=500, scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 25000))
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
canvas.update_idletasks()

vbar = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient='vertical')
vbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have 0 experience with python, but is  scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 25000) correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your vertical scrollbar is so long because you set `scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 25000)` which means that you scroll `y` between 0 and 25000.

To adapt the scrollregion to the content of canvas, you can do (after putting everything you want inside the canvas):

`canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))`

`canvas.bbox('all')` returns the area of the canvas that contains items.